# Make OAuth 2 Authorization Code Grant/Flow without user intervention

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, postman, microsoft-identity-platform

Trying to access an API resource that requires the Grant Type Authorization code. I can get back a valid Access Code using Postman and it's Authorization tool.

[image]

This involves Postman popping up a login window where I enter the username and password.

How can I accomplish this purely problematically without user intervention? This Grant Type seems to be the only one that works with this API as when I just try and use the client_id and client_secret with the Client Credentials flow the Access Token I get back does not allow me into the API (401).

I am looking to do this as code agnostic as possible. That is I would like to be able to do it without relying a library that does things behind the scenes. Ideally everything would be done via HTTP like with cURL.

I have some C# code that does what I am looking for but it makes use of the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` library (`older version 2.29.0.1078`). It seems to be able to get a token by passing in the username and password

```
string userName = "johndoe";
string password = "mydoghasfleas";
string clientId = "7934579357js487dhj444";
clientBaseUrl = "https://mycompanyname.dynamics.com";
apiEndpointUrl = clientBaseUrl + "/data/resource=XYZ";

UserCredential credential = new UserCredential(userName, password);
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(apiEndpointUrl, false);
AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(clientBaseUrl, clientID, credential);
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to do it without depending on the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was one of your APIs, the correct approach would be to add support for client credentials auth and app permissions in the API. Seeing that it's probably Dynamics, that's probably not possible for you. In that case, you can use authorization code flow to get initial tokens for a user, and then you can use the refresh token to get a new token when needed. In the final case, you can use Resource Owner Password Credentials flow to get tokens. But beware, this flow does not support MFA etc.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. You are correct it is Dynamic 365 and I don’t have control of the environment. When you say MFA are you referring to Multi Factor Authentication? I am a little confused when you say “In the final case”, because you described two different flows. Authorization code flow and Resource Owner Password Credential flow. Which do you think is better to choose assuming I don’t want to use an external library?

Comment: Authorization code flow + refresh token flow are the more secure option. It also allows the user account to have Multi-Factor Authentication. ROPC flow is simpler to implement, it is an HTTP call to the Azure AD token endpoint that gives you tokens in exchange for user + app credentials. The downside of it is that you are handling a user password + that user account cannot have Multi-Factor Authentication enabled. Dynamics will definitely support both of these flows, it doesn't know what flow was used to get the token. All it cares about is that there is user info in the token.

Comment: For authz code flow, you really do need a library (or risk implementing it wrong). ROPC is pretty simple: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc.

Comment: Client credentials flow is for machine to machine communication. But question seems to be for user to machine communication (user credentials are used). Why you recommend Client credentials flow?

Comment: If one wants to connect to an API without user interaction, that is usually service to service communication. Dynamics does not support this, so it isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Hackish: you can do UI parsing and then just mimic standard user login procedure

Proper approach will be to use better flow, which is allowed by used IdP, e.g. Direct Grant Flow (Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant flow)`.

Comment: I can see it working using the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` library (updated original question), so it must be possible without screen scraping.